# ImportError with "Import PyQt5.QtSql "

Tags: pyqt5

I am attempting to

```
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery
```

and am receiving this error:

from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery
ImportError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtSql'

I haven't yet ran into an import problem with other PyQt5 modules.  Is the QtSql module installed separately?

thanks,

Comment: How have you installed pyqt5?

Comment: Same problem? https://github.com/ghostop14/sparrow-wifi/issues/1

Comment: oh, sorry, misread your question...  I installed PyQt5 as:

    apt-get install python3-pyqt5

Comment: @FrEaKmAn, thanks for the link, while working through that page, I determined that the following command:

apt-get install python3-pyqt5.qtsql

did the job.  many thanks.

Comment: Sure, added answer to be accepted. @aureliabulldog

Answer (score 5):

There is a similar problem described at https://github.com/ghostop14/sparrow-wifi/issues/1

Solution described there is to run command

```
apt-get install python3-pyqt5.qtsql
```